# Dynamic Independent Title for Each Object in Array

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

In the process of creating an alpaca form, I came across a situation in which I am unsure how to proceed.

Here is a representation of the schema I am using:

```
$("#samplediv").alpaca({
  "schema": {
    "description": "My Favorite Ice Creams",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Ice Cream",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "flavor": {
                "title": "Flavor",
                "description": "Ice cream flavor",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "topping": {
                "title": "Topping",
                "description": "Ice cream topping",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

The rendered schema looks like this:

[image: Ice Cream Schema]

I have an array of objects, comprised of text fields. My goal is to create a dynamic and independent title for each object in the array, based on data the object contains. In the example case, this could be replacing the 'Ice Cream' title with 'Vanilla' for the first object, and 'Chocolate' for the second object.

I've tried using the *postRender* callback to set the title property of each object in the array container based on current field data, though I can't seem to get the text to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing some hack, but by default the Array type of fields usually uses the same title for every item created. What you need to do is to change the title after changing the Flavor field and this will be made by using a change event in that field.

```
"flavor": {
      "events": {
        "change": function() {
          changeItemLabel(this.parent, this.getValue());
        }
      }
    }
```

This will do the trick, but all newly created items will have the same updated title! So the idea that comes in mind is to use kind of a default label and override the updated title of the newly created item.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/yfa6bqon/) demonstrating this case.
I hope this helps you but tell me if this isn't what your looking for.

Comment: That solved the dynamic title bug! Is it possible to make those titles clickable for collapsing each object? I've tried adding the collapse data-toggle with success, but I'm searching for a cleaner solution! (why aren't objects collapsible like the other container objects?)

Comment: for the collapse to work there's an option to activate it, I tried it but it didn't work... I'll try it again maybe today after work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Alpacajs documentation is a big mess and several features are not described. And several of the examples just don't work. So you'll have to dig into the source to figure out how it works. :(

To enable collapsing, you'll have to place the code INSIDE the "items" part of your options, like this:

```
"options": {
    "myfield": {
        "toolbarSticky": true,
        "toolbarPosition": "bottom",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "collapsible": true,
            "fields": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```